requiring password for specific folders in Samba
I am extremely green when it comes to Linux.  I recently set my first Ubuntu server for home use and learning on.  I have 1 windows PC that will have access to the Samba share.   My question is, is there a way to require a password for a specific folder in the share?  I.E. in my samba share I have a folder for media, documents, work.  I want to require a password for say the documents folder.
When setting up the folders I have used this for each folder
chown nobody:no group /srv/samba/share/<folder>

Why not just create separate shares for media, documents, and work. Then you can configure each one separate from the others.
